# What can I use to give hints about forgotten memories without repeating myself?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, campaign-development

I am building a campaign for my players. I want them to have been experimented on by some evil wizard/sorcerer, and have lost memories of what happened, only knowing that something major happened and that they aren't the same as they were before.
I have ideas like an enemy with a mind affecting attack triggering flashback, finding old workshops, notes, journals, messages of the wizard but am stuck for more.

**What can I do to clue my players into the past without doing the same thing repeatedly?**

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. I recommend you take the [Tour]—we do things a little differently here. We’re pretty strictly about Q&A, not discussion. The site’s format is explicitly designed to get straight to answers, and limit discussion—so when discussion is necessary, the site does poorly. As a result, we don’t handle requests for ideas or opinions; we need questions we can answer directly. Instead, we suggest that you check out a discussion forum for this kind of thing: we even have [a list of recommendations](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5449/4563) for you.

Comment: I'm looking for ideas for recovering information on the past. So I need to phrase it more as a question to work better for this site?

Comment: Since the site's goal is expert information from experts, what we need is something where we can say "I did something like this, here's what I did, here's how it worked out," or "This is a tried and true method for getting your PCs to notice stuff" rather than asking us to give you whatever we think is cool. Does that make sense? It does help if you do phrase it more as a question though.

Answer (score 2):

I ran a campaign with an amnesiac character once upon a time.  Some of the things I gave him as clues were: he understood certain languages that weren't local to the city the PCs were in at the time, and in fact spoke with an accent (though it took someone else telling him this, of course).  At various times, when he did, saw, or heard something, I'd tell the player this seemed familiar in some way.  At one point, he automatically cast a simple spell to light a lamp (this was in a game system that didn't require daily spell preparation), cluing him that his character was a mage and knew that particular spell.

This went on until the campaign broke up due to time conflicts; by that time, I was working in plots related to *how* the character lost his memory (beaten for head trauma while trying to escape virtual slavery and left for dead, rescued by a mysterious healer).